# Reactive Form Array with Radio Buttons

Tags: angular, typescript, arraylist

I have problems with reactive forms and an array of radio buttons. My problem is I only can select single package not multiple package.How should I do so that I can select multiple package. This is my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-group-wrapper-xmfugk) demo.
My Form looks like this:

[image]

And This my example code

**HTML**

```
<div class="card col-8 shadow-sm">
    <div class="list-group">
        <form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.valid && onSubmit()">
        <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start" *ngFor="let list of packages ; list as index; let i of index">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <h5 class="card-title pr-3 d-inline-block font-weight-bold">{{list.eventName}}</h5>
                </span>
               </div>

                <p class="card-text">
                    {{list.eventNote}}
                </p>
                <div>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold pr-2">Attendings :</span>
                    <span class="ml-5">
                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="attendings"  aria-label="Select an option">
                        <mat-radio-button value="y">Yes</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button value="n">No</mat-radio-button>
                      </mat-radio-group>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-60 mt-4">
                    <div class="card  card-line col-md-12 mb-3" *ngFor="let fee of list.feeList">
                         <div class="card-body ctrl-height">
                         <input type="radio" formControlName="fee" id="{{fee.feeId}}" [value]="fee">
                         <label for="{{fee.feeId}}">
                          <span class="id-conf">{{fee.category}}</span>
                          <span class="price">{{fee.price}}</span>
                        </label>
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
     </div>
     <div class="card-footer no-gutters ctrl-lr">
        <div class="card-body float-right"> 
            {{form.value | json}}
            <a (click)="submit()"  class="btn btn-primary  card-link d-inline pl-4 pr-4">Next </a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Component**

```
packages = packages;

   form = new FormGroup({
    attendings: new FormControl,
    fee: new FormControl

   });
  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have arrays of packages in your `package-list` component, but you have only one `FormGroup` with `attendings` and `fee` FormControls for all of these packages. That's why whatever you select, it overwrites only available `FormGroup`.

You should use [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)

**In your `package-list.component.ts`**

```js
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

...

export class PackagesListComponent implements OnInit {

  packages = packages;

  // generate array of FormGroup
  controls = packages.map(pack => {
    return new FormGroup({
      attendings: new FormControl(),
      fee: new FormControl()
    });
  });

  // gengerate main FormGroup containing our FormArray
  // FormArray will contain our generated FormGroups with necessary FormControls
  form = new FormGroup({
    formArray: new FormArray(this.controls)
  });

  // this getter will be used in the template to get the formArray
  get myFormArray() {
    return this.form.get('formArray') as FormArray;
  }

  ...


}
```

**In your `package-list.component.html`**

```html
<div class="card col-8 shadow-sm">
    <div class="list-group">
        <form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.valid && submit()">
        <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start" *ngFor="let list of packages; let i = index">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <h5 class="card-title pr-3 d-inline-block font-weight-bold">{{list.eventName}}</h5>
                </span>
               </div>

                <p class="card-text">
                    {{list.eventNote}}
                </p>
                <div>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold pr-2">Attendings :</span>
                    <span class="ml-5">
                    <mat-radio-group [formControl]="myFormArray.at(i).get('attendings')"  aria-label="Select an option">
                        <mat-radio-button value="y">Yes</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button value="n">No</mat-radio-button>
                      </mat-radio-group>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-60 mt-4">
                    <div class="card  card-line col-md-12 mb-3" *ngFor="let fee of list.feeList">
                         <div class="card-body ctrl-height">
                         <input type="radio" [formControl]="myFormArray.at(i).get('fee')" id="{{fee.feeId}}" [value]="fee">
                         <label for="{{fee.feeId}}">
                          <span class="id-conf">{{fee.category}}</span>
                          <span class="price">{{fee.price}}</span>
                        </label>
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
     </div>
     <div class="card-footer no-gutters ctrl-lr">
        <div class="card-body float-right"> 
            {{form.value | json}}
            <a (click)="submit()"  class="btn btn-primary  card-link d-inline pl-4 pr-4">Next </a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I have done several things here:

1. updated your `*ngFor` in line number 4:
   `<div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start" *ngFor="let list of packages; let i = index">`
2. change the line number 18:
   `<mat-radio-group [formControl]="myFormArray.at(i).get('attendings')"  aria-label="Select an option">`
3. change the line number 27:
   `<input type="radio" [formControl]="myFormArray.at(i).get('fee')" id="{{fee.feeId}}" [value]="fee">`

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? if I got data from API..What should I do?

Comment: In that case, you have to generate `form` and `controls` inside the subscription of the `httpClient`

Comment: Could you give me example...Because when I try to add `form` and `controls` inside the subscription I got error..